# Не могу составить код который будет вычислять четное/нечетное число на python

Tags: python, print

Суть кода в том что - 'Пользователь вводит число (a). Найти количество всех нечетных чисел, на диапазоне
Я настрогал пару строчек кода, но все равно не выходит в ответе. Когда ввожу даже 1 число просто ничего не выводиться, и даже причину не могу понять.

```
a= input('Введите первое число:')
def sum():
     if a / 2 == 0:
           print ('четное число')
     else:
          print ('Нечетное число')
```

Comment: @Интик Попробовал сделать sum(a) ничего не изменилось, с табуляциями и пробелом все ок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я так понимаю, тебе нужно найти количество чётных чисел в определенном вводимом диапазоне.

```
num1 = int(input('Введи первое число: ')) // Пользователь вводит первое число
num2 = int(input ('Введите второе число: ')) // Пользователь вводит второе число
k = 0 // Добавляем переменную куда будем плюсовать количество чётных чисел

for i in range(num1,num2+1): // Создаём цикл в диапазоне введённых цифр (+1 во втором аргументе, потому что в range доходит ДО числа, а не ДО ВКЛЮЧИТЕЛЬНО этого числа)
    if i % 2 == 0: // Проверяем на чётность (если чётное делаем:)
        k +=1 // Если число чётное +1
print (k)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Введённое значение преобразовать в число при помощи функции `int()`.
2. Проверять остаток от деления `a % 2 == 0`.
3. Ну и функцию таки следует вызвать `sum()`.

```
a = int(input('Введите первое число: '))
def sum():
     if a % 2 == 0:
          print ('четное число')
     else:
          print ('Нечетное число')
sum()
```

*P.S. Вообще-то есть встроенная функция с таким именем, так что называя свою так же вы лишаетесь доступа к ней. Так что лучше не называть что-либо стандартными именами.*